# Bootstrap: Col-md-4 nowhere NEAR 33.3% Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a really weird problem with col-md-4 in bootstrap.

It's behaving as if it's nested inside a div set at about 33% width (i.e. each col-md-4 ends up being 11.1% width of the total page).

The thing is, col-md-4 is only nested inside 2 other divs, both set at 100% width.

I've been fiddling around with this for about an hour now and nothing works. The only theory I have is that something is causing col-md-4 to be treated like its own container (I realize that sounds silly but the whole area with col-md-4s inside it is for some reason 33.3% width).

Some relevant css

```
.container-fluid {
padding-right: 0%;
padding-left: 0%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 100%;
}

.col-md-12 {
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-md-12.alpha {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
}

.col-md-4 {
width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

And the html

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-static-top">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 alpha">
    <div class="headline1">
        <div class="col-md-4 alpha">
            <h1>lorem ipsem<br> lorem ipsem<h1><br>
            <p class="arial">lorem ipsem<br> lorem ipsem<br>lorem ipsem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 beta">
            <img src='images/appleproducts/appleproducts.png'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 alpha" style="background: white;"> 

    <h>hi</h><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src=url('images/icons/iphone26.png');
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First off, try to fix your html first (you have 2 unclosed tags and strangely looking img src parameter), then put everything on jsfiddle end explain what would you expect it to look like

Comment: You need to put the columns within a class of row.